# whats next? After setting up CentOS 6 x64, I need to set up a web user I can SSH/sFTP in with

Tags: php, lamp

I just finished doing a LAMP install on a CentOS 6 x64 install.

I have had LAMP server before this one, and I would always ssh into the server as root but i'm trying to make a production environment and i would like to make a user that I can log in with that isn't root or has root privileges.

I noticed that in some of my PHP scripts that create files using the `fopen()` functions that it sets the user and group to apache.

What would i need to do is I wanted to have a user called `optik` and a group called `nerv` (just examples). Also when PHP makes new files and or folders how can i get it so that it too uses that same `user` and `groups`?

At this point I just have a fresh LAMP install from SoftLayer and nothing else other than MySQL server running on it as well. (no yum updates or anything of the sort yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suphp is what you need if you want to run php scripts as a specific user:

http://www.suphp.org/Home.html

You should try to find a howto for your Centos distribution to set it up correctly.